# How to send post data on success redirect with passport?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, passport.js

I am trying to post data through my login form. I am using passport to authenticate the users credentials. Typically to post data through a form I use:

```
app.post('/login_mrkt', (req,res) => {
  console.log(req) //Contains post data from form
}
```

However as I want to authenticate the user I use the below code:

```
app.post('/login_mrkt', checkNotAuthenticated, passport.authenticate('local', {
    successRedirect: '/dash',
    failureRedirect: '/login',
    failureFlash: true
}))
```

When the login is successful it redirects my user to `/dash` get. However this does not contain the post data from the form:

```
app.get('/dash', checkAuthenticated, (req,res) => {
    console.log(req) //This does not contain post data, but I want it to
})
```

How can I make it so I can retrieve the post data from my fomr in the `/dash` get?

**Edit**

Here is my checkAuthenticated method as requested:

```
function checkAuthenticated(req, res, next) {
    if (req.isAuthenticated()) {
        return next()//can think of next() as go to the next function in the request call back function
    }
    res.redirect('/login')
}
```

Comment: You can put the post data in session once you hit the `/login_mrkt`, then retrieve it back in the `/dash` and clear the session.

Comment: Can you share your checkAuthenticated middleware?

Comment: @ionut-t I have added it to my question.

Comment: @NileshSingh Would you be able to help show me how to do this? Thanks